# manage.py not generated when using "django-admin startapp mysite"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to setup a webapp using the django framework. Following the tutorial, when I use "django-admin startapp {project-name}", django-admin correctly generates:

```
06/08/2016  10:21 AM    <DIR>          .
06/08/2016  10:21 AM    <DIR>          ..

06/08/2016  10:21 AM                63 admin.py
06/08/2016  10:21 AM                97 apps.py
06/08/2016  10:21 AM    <DIR>          migrations
06/08/2016  10:21 AM                57 models.py
06/08/2016  10:21 AM                60 tests.py
06/08/2016  10:21 AM                63 views.py
06/08/2016  10:21 AM                 0 __init__.py
               6 File(s)            340 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  91,039,383,552 bytes free
```

But not manage.py.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am working in a virtual environment (which I didn't last time it worked) with just django installed if that makes a difference.

Edit: 
I just tested creating an app outside the virtual environment and the same problem was prominent - no manage.py.

I use django 1.9.7, and it seems like I used django 1.8.x when it worked last.

Comment: @sayse when going up one directory, I'm inside my virtualenv "root-folder" in which I ran the command "django-admin startapp mysite"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`manage.py` is included in projects not apps. To create a new project, you should do:

```
django-admin startproject {project-name}
```

Projects are a collection of apps. So to create an app, `cd` into the project directory you've just created and do:

```
django-admin startapp {app-name}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I know the difference between projects and apps then. Am I not making an web-**app**?

When using startproj, it doesn't recognize the command it responds: (TRYDJA~1) C:\Users\Kasper\OneDrive\Projects\Personal Website\_Home\trydjango19env>django-admin startproj trydjango19
No Django settings specified.
Unknown command: 'startproj'
Type 'django-admin help' for usage.

Comment: you can create a project and then create many apps in the project.

Comment: Using django-admin help I see it's startproject not startproj

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MosesKoledoye

Comment: You can find more info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your old project and start creating a new project again. Even I faced the same problem and this worked for me.
After installing django using the command

> pip install django

Create a project using the following command

> django-admin startproject name_of_your_project